# List View Migration using Changeset

Tags: lightning, health-cloud

I've made a custom listview in Health Cloud Lightning Admin Patients List View with some custom logic. How can I migrate it from one organization to another using Change Set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select the List Views from the Components list and then add the same to the Change Set. But just make sure that the Filter Criteria of the List View(s) which you are unable to add to the Change Set are not filtered by a Queue.

We have the known issue created for the same:https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p300000001AHTAA2

Also refer: Components Available in Change Sets (https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=changesets_about_components.htm&language=en)

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you so much. We've to do it manually to set the logic again in the different sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

A List View can be migrated using ChangeSets. You need to choose the List View Component to select your List View.
Here is a consolidated list of items that can be migrated using Changeset.

[List of components migrated using changeset](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=changesets_about_components.htm&type=5)